# Can Superset connect to SAP Datasphere?

Tags: hana, apache-superset, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm trying to connect a Superset instance to [SAP Datasphere](https://stackoverflow.com) and I'm getting the following error :

> `ERROR: (builtins.NoneType) None [SQL: (hdbcli.dbapi.Error) (-10709, 'Connection failed (RTE:[89008] Socket closed by peer (host info))') (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)`

When I use the same connection string to connect through [sql-alchemy](https://github.com/SAP/sqlalchemy-hana) the connection is successful and it's working. Also, I have ruled out connectivity issues because I'm testing from the same machine.

Can Superset connect to Datasphere or it can only use other types of hana connections?